# Should we avoid division of nearby numbers in numerical computation?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I learned from class that in numerical computation on should avoid subtraction of two nearby numbers. For example, when the subtraction is a denominator, it would introduce significant error.

I am asking should we avoid the same thing for division, i.e. avoid division of two nearby numbers?

Comment: In general, no. Relative errors are well-behaved in multiplication and division.

Comment: Are you aware *why* you can get significant numerical error on subtraction?

Comment: You should always avoid division. But not for that reason but because division is slow as f*ck in hardware and not pipelineable.

Comment: @mathreadler: "numerical computation" is usually done in floating point, and floating point $+,-,*,/$ take similar speeds

Comment: @Dap : No, / is slower than the rest by a large margin even on modern CPUs.

Comment: @mathreadler: you're right - I must have misremembered the fact that that $+,-,*$ take (roughly) similar speeds in floating point

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4125033/5108790 here are some interesting answers if you are interested in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. To repeat an answer given in comments: floating point error is (roughly speaking) relative error, and relative errors are well-behaved in multiplication and division.

In fact $x/y=2(x/2y)$ will usually hold (assuming no underflow), which shows that $x/y$ does not introduce more relative error than $x/2y$.